# NHibernate with Sql Server Compact Edition and skip/take

Tags: nhibernate, sql-server-ce

I'm using NHibernate 3.3.3.4000 and SQL Server CE 4.0.8876.1, and I can't get it to work with paging (skip and take).  I'm seeing contradictory things about SQL CE's support for it.

Does Nhibernate's SQL CE driver support skip and take?  The generated SQL does not include any skip/take syntax.  But I see on some blog syntax like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders
ORDER BY OrderID
OFFSET 20 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

When I try that in Visual Studio Server Explorer, it doesn't like that.  My program is apparently fetching everything from the database, then applying paging locally.  Obviously that gives pretty awful performance.  I got an error when I tried to make it a future query, so I stopped doing that.

For reference, my Fluent NHibernate configuration is

```
    var cfg = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(MsSqlCeConfiguration.Standard
        .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("SampleDatabase"))
        .AdoNetBatchSize(500)
        .FormatSql())
    .Mappings(mappings => mappings.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<PositionMapping>())
    .Cache(c => c.ProviderClass<SysCacheProvider>())
    .BuildConfiguration();
```

and my query is

```
var baseQuery = session.QueryOver<Position>();
var countQuery = baseQuery.ToRowCountQuery().FutureValue<int>();
items = baseQuery
.Left.JoinAlias(p => p.PublicText, () => publicTextAlias)
.Left.JoinAlias(p => p.RegisteredText, () => registeredTextAlias)
.Fetch(p => p.Term).Eager
.Fetch(p => p.Tags).Eager
.OrderBy(p => p.OpenDate).Desc
.CacheMode(NHibernate.CacheMode.Ignore)
.Skip(skip).Take(BatchSize)
//.Future(); // Causes error
.List<Position>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes NHibernate does support features of the SQL Server CE for pagination. The way it is done, is by selecting the correct dialect.

With standard configuration, you'd have to provide setting like this:

```
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCe40Dialect</property>
```

With fluent, it should be like:

```
.Database(MsSqlCeConfiguration.Standard
    .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("SampleDatabase"))
    ...
    .Dialect("NHibernate.Dialect.MsSqlCe40Dialect")
    ...
```

Comment: That does add the OFFSET x ROWS FETCH NEXT y ROWS ONLY to my queries. However, my query still takes a very long time to execute, so something else is also going on.